# How to share properties between class instances and other possible users of those properties?

Tags: java, class, design-patterns

Say that there are multiple classes {*C1*, *C2*, ...} which implement an interface *I*, containing, among other things, methods called *getColor()*, *getName()*, and *move()*. Every instance of *C1* returns the **same** value when *getColor()* and *getName()* are called, same with *C2* and all of the other classes that implement *I*. Move is defined per class, too, but is affected by instance variables and may not behave the same way per instance. The implementations of *getColor()* and *getName()* in the *C1* class might look like:

```
public Color getColor() {
    return Color.RED;
}

public String getName() {
    return "C1!!!";
}
```

All objects implementing the interface *I* can be added to and drawn to a screen. Suppose, however, that the way in which those objects are added, is through a different screen, with buttons on it. When one of those buttons is clicked, it signals to the application that the type of object associated with the clicked should be added to the screen.

If the goal is to label the button associated with *C1* with the String returned by *C1*'s *getName()* and color the button with the Color returned *C1*'s *getColor()*, one could instantiate a new instance of *C1*, and then retrieve its name and color to customize its associated button:

```
...
I instance = new C1();
Button C1Button = new Button();
C1Button.setLabel(instance.getName());
C1Button.setColor(instance.getColor());
...
```

... and then instantiate a new instance of *C2* and *C3* and ... and *C50*, following the same process as with *C1*.

This seems rather dirty though, the classes are no longer being instantiated for the sake of fulfilling the other methods in *I*, but just to obtain the *color* and *name* properties for the buttons. Furthermore, that would be a awful lot of code. Can anyone provide suggestions as to how the *color* and *name* properties could be **decoupled** from the classes implementing *I*, so as to **reduce the length of code required** if the number of classes implementing *I* grows dramatically past two? Are there any specific design patterns that might be used to resolve this?

Comment: is there any business logic changes between C1 and C2? not values, but logic?

Comment: Yes, possibly. I'll add that to the question!

Comment: it looks like you need static array with object instances, so instances will be reused

Comment: doesn't the reuse of instances make the fact that move differs per instance a problem?

Comment: no, you could have something like `I[] array = new I[]{new C1(), new C2()...,};`

Comment: just to confirm `move` behaves differently for each instance or each class?

Comment: class. my bad..

Comment: then array approach should work, so you will be able to turn your button creation code into simple loop, onclick handler will be able to use different instance of object from pool (array)

Comment: ok. and you think that's an ok practice?

Comment: Its hard to say without know everything about the system you're implementing, but generally there is nothing wrong with constant objects

Comment: @IlyaBursov array is not good since a) you have to store it somewhere b) you should update it when new class has been created c) you could do nothing but only iterate through the array. Enum, as Matt suggests, is much better since a) and c) is not relevant for enum.

Comment: @ADS a) is relevant for enum too, I don't understand c). Technically enum is array internally, so there is no conceptual difference.

Comment: @IlyaBursov a) The difference that array stored in a field or variable inside some class. And that raises issues: how to get access from other class if needed? How to make sure nobody would change this array from another thread? c) You are [wrong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), in java **enum is a class** extends `java.lang.Enum` It's a crucial moment

Comment: @ADS how will you implement method values for enum?

Comment: @IlyaBursov just see the [tutorial fom Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)`public enum Plane { <private and public fields> <some code> double surfaceGravity() { /*use fields*/}

Comment: @IlyaBursov I personally has created enum which contains public abstract and private classes which do some stuff. And it works on production. Such enums has  been in Java for <s>ages</s> since Java 5 i.e. for more than decade

Comment: @ADS I mean - if you were JDK developer, how would you implement method `values` in `java.lang.Enum`?

Comment: @IlyaBursov I don't need to dream about. I could see source for `java.lang.Enum`. But it's out of scope. I suppose any java developer should know that enum is a class and could contain any fields, constructors and methods. It's very different from array which cant have additional data than given from JDK

Comment: @ADS just to close discussion - enum **is** array, or you can say it is syntactic sugar around immutable array, with named indexes. This is why enum can return list of all declared constants (because internally it is array), every enum instance has `ordinal` (because it is index in this internal array). So there is not **conceptual** difference.

Comment: @IlyaBursov just re-read Java basics. It's different than in another languages

Comment: @ADS how exactly enum is different in other languages? (of course languages which have such feature explicitly, implicitly - all language with arrays provide similar function)

Comment: @IlyaBursov I agree we have to close the discussion - it's out of initial question. You could find answer at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345825/difference-of-enum-in-c-and-java)

Comment: @ADS you're right about different languages, I've completely forgot that some of them define enum values only as integers, I stand corrected. Anyway, in java enum is array with named indexes, or you can treat it as `Map` (which is technically also array)

Answer (score 1):

I usually do that sort of thing by making an enum like this, separate from the implementation classes

```
public enum TypeOfC
{
    C1(Color.RED, C1::new),
    //you don't have to use different classes for every one!
    CX(Color.BLACK, () -> new C1(5)),
    C2(Color.BLUE, C2::new);

    private final Color m_color;
    private final Supplier<I> m_constructor;

    TypeOfC(Color color, Supplier<I> ctor)
    {
        m_color = color;
        m_constructor = ctor;
    }

    public Color getColor()
    {
        return m_color;
    }

    public I create()
    {
        return m_ctor.get();
    }
}
```

Then you can make buttons like:

```
for (TypeOfC t : TypeOfC.values())
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.setColor(t.getColor());
    b.setLabel(t.name());  // make a different getter if you don't want the enum constant name
    b.setAction(()->doWatever(t.create()));
    allButtons.add(b);
}
```

Comment: Do you use enum as a factory for C1-C2-Cx? Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer that I found involves using something like the [type object](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/type-object.html) pattern. It seems to be conceptually related to Matt's suggestion. Instead of defining multiple different classes that inherit from *I*, only one class, *C* needs to be defined, which accepts another class, *Properties*, in its constructor. All properties of *C* can then be retrieved from the *Properties* class associated with it:

```
public class C implements I {
    private final Properties properties;

    public C(Properties p) {
        this.properties = p;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}
```

The properties can all be defined in a *PropertyDictionary*. When constructing new *C*'s, the appropriate properties for an object can be grabbed from the *PropertyDictionary*. This way, the classes inheriting from *I* still maintain the same functionality (in a changed method name, though) and other accesors of the data can learn what they want to about the possible values that *C* can take by querying the PropertyDictionary:

```
Properties p = new Properties("Class name", Color.YELLER);
I instance = new C(p);
// instance.getProperties().getColor() == p.getColor(); --> True
...
for(Properties prop : PropertyDictionary.getProperties()) {
    Button b = new Button();
    b.setLabel(prop.getName());
    b.setColor(prop.getColor());
}
```

Multiple instances of *C* with the same *Properties* all reference the same *Properties* instance in the *PropertyDictionary*, somewhat like in [Flyweight](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html):

```
final Properties p = new Properties("Cat", Color.BLACK);
List<I> cats = new ArrayList<>(1000);

// make 1000 black cats:
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    cats.add(new C(p));
}
```