# Is there an equivalent in C++ for java enums that look like this?

Tags: c++, enums

i've been trying to port my java code into c++ using structs or constructors but they none seem to fit for something like DEBUGNAME(id,name,description);

````
public enum blockInfo {

    SWIVEL("swiv1","swivel joint","A swivel joint, unpowered"),
    ARMOR("arm1","armor","A structurally sound block that protects from hits"),
    BATTERY("batt1","battery","A battery, stores energy from generators and depletes as a component draws from it");

    private string id;
    private string name;
    private string description;

    private blockInfo(string id, string name, string description)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

}```
````

Comment: Did you search for e.g. _c++ java enum_? There are plenty answers out there already.

Comment: My recommendation when porting or translating code from one language to another is to not do a literal translation. Literals translations (between programming, written or spoken languages) will almost never turn out well. Instead take the underlying algorithm or design, and reimplement it using the other language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference of Enum between java and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080681/difference-of-enum-between-java-and-c)